# How can I use a key value as a variable name in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, json, variables, object

I want to be able to take JSON into my program and then create objects based off of that data. So, I want to create objects where the name of that object is the value stored in a key value pair. For instance, if I had the following JSON (and I know this isn't perfect JSON):

```
{
    "objectName" : "**variableName**",
    "someDataName" : "thatData",
    "someOtherDataName" : "thisData"
}
```

Then I want to be able to make an object like this:

```
function myObject(thatData, thisData) {
    this.name = name;
    this.thatData = thatData;
}

var **variableName** = new myObject(thatData, thisData);
```

The key here is that I want to be able to use the value stored in the ObjectName key value pair as the variable name for the object. Is this even possible? I have been looking for how to do this for a while now. I believe that this is different than ["Variable" variables in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5187530/variable-variables-in-javascript/37575407#37575407) because I am trying to use a value in a key value pair to name my objects.

Comment: you can check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5187530/variable-variables-in-javascript/37575407#37575407

Comment: I believe that my question is different than the one that you mentioned, as I am trying to use a JSON value in a key/value pair to create my variable name.

Comment: @NickP: Where the value comes from is irrelevant. You want to use the value of a string as variable name. That's all that matters.

Comment: @NickP I am giving example of key type object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you're trying to do here, one approach may be to set properties within a variable:

```
let myContainer = {};
// ...
myContainer['whatever_variable_name'] = new ...
```

You can how use `myContainer.whatever_variable_name` or `myContainer['whatever_variable_name']` to access the new object.

To assign properties from JSON objects, see [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [property accessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors) on the [window](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window) object to set the value for a dynamic key on the global scope.

```
var window["**variableName**"] = new myObject(thatData, thisData);
```